# Trying to get USB Vag-Com/VCDS cable to work under wine (ebay cable)

Tags: linux, usb, arch-linux, wine

I've been following this guide: http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?2725554
and this guide: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=220200&page=2

and obviously quite easily i got the program installed, however I'm having trouble creating a symbolic link for the usb cable. Did some searching and obviously a lot of the car guys aren't very tech savvy and just say "switch to windows"

Comment: What trouble specifically?

Comment: trying to get the USB OBD2 cable to work and get the drivers installed under wine for the scanning program to see the cable, also has to be set to COM3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like the new VCDS Adapters are no FTDI usb 2 serial port adapters.
This means, the correct com1 config for wine does no longer suffice as the cable does not provide a tty.
I am currently trying to find additional info on the adapters but it looks like a virtual box will be the only solution, if any.